# Spring boot value injection

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have created a simple spring boot application, and I would like to set string value to field in component (class annotated with @Component), but I get an exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'rounding.strategy' in value "${rounding.strategy}"
```

I am absolutely sure that `application.properties` file contains this value. I'm also sure that my `application.properties` file is located in right directory (`src/main/resources/application.properties`).

This is how I try set this value:

```
@Value("${rounding.strategy}")
private String actualStrategyBeanName;
```

This is how I set it in `application.properties` file:

```
rounding.strategy = sprbj_FiftyRoundingStrategy
```

`build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Intellij IDEA Ultimate shows injected value correct (see screenshot [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEerj.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEerj.png)), but spring can't set it into field.
What did I do wrong?

**EDIT**
I tried annotated main class with `@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")` annotation, and after that I got

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Comment: Tried to remove spaces in application.properties?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the resources folder one level outside:

like this:

```
src/main/resources/application.properties
```

Comment: Oups, sorry, I made a mistake in question. Resource folder already in the src/main/ directory. This is right directory, isn't it?

Comment: Try deleting the .idea folder and re-import the project again.